# Update ULabel immediately while downloading files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, performselector

I am using NSURLConnection to download the files . I have a UILabel in my View which has to display the currently downloading files. The UILabel is getting updated at the starting and the end. Lets say I am download 10 files. I am able to set the Label text before start downloading and after completing the download.

I can understand that, the method which I am trying to call is not running in main thread,

So I have used the following code to make it run in the main thread ,

```
[_myHome performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateLabel) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

and method is

```
- (void) updateLabel
 {
         _fileName.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileName];
 }
```

This also seems to be not working. Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Can anyone tell me how to update the label immediately ??

Comment: Looks ok - waituntildone can be NO, and if why not just _filename.text = fileName.  When things like this are not working, first step should be to use NSLog()/breakpoints to check the methods are actually being called.  Have you done that?

Comment: Yes. I have used NSLog. I didn't those lines in my question. Actually the updateLabel method is getting called. But the Label is not updated.

Comment: what about the `fileName` check whether `fileName` is not an empty string.

Comment: _fileName is not nil? And points to the correct label? 99% of the time things like this are due to small oversights. Also, note you can use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ _fileName.text = fileName }); to avoid having the extra method call.

Comment: is this `_fileName` is an IBOutlet of yours?

Comment: @MathewVarghese . I tried add my name in the Label too. Like _fileName.text =@"Perseus"; That Doesn't make sense too.

Comment: @Ayaz . I didn't wrote much coding for label. Just added in the xib and trying to set the Text here.

Comment: If this label is in XIB then check whether you connected the label with the IBOutlet of your class or not. If it is an IBOutlet try call like `self._fileName.text = @"Something";`(It its a property).

Comment: @MathewVarghese. Yes. _fileName is nothing but the IBOutlet UILabel

Comment: @MathewVarghese. Please check my question, that I have mentioned that it is working fine in the start and end. Please !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED : I used NSNotificationCenter to send notifications to other class, which will update the labels immediately. I tried with performSelectorOnMainThread, even if both the updateProgress, performSelectorOnMainThread is in same class.

Any reasons for why it didn't worked out , is most welcome.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    //update your label 
}
```

Comment: Oops. That is in Different class. Anyway even if I try to update my label in this delegate method , it won't work. Because didReceiveData still runs in the main thread.

Comment: You can control the progress of your download ONLY in the method specified above. If that method is in another class, implement a delegate of that class so didReceiveData: will send messages to your current class, and there, try updating the label on main thread.

Comment: Downloading files is working properly. And FYI , we shouldn't call the methods in the didReceiveData, which will keep on recieve the data. We should call the methods when the connectionDidFinishLoading. And also I am trying to update the UILabel in one the delegate methods of NSURLConnection.

Comment: If you need to monitor the download piece by piece, use the method I have specified. if you just cannot update the label due to thread matters, play around waitUntilDone (Y/N) in didFinishLoading.