# performSelectorOnMainThread over Notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

I have some basic doubt's, guess someone will help me out.

Please refer this Question : [Update ULabel immediately while downloading files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411373/update-ulabel-immediately-while-downloading-files/)

I have tried using `performSelectorOnMainThread` , which is calling the updateProgress method in another class and but the label is not updating.

But now I have used the notification like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateProgress" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

which seems to be calling the method and also updating the UILabel. Eventhough my problem is resolved, I want to know why the above `performSelectorOnMainThread` didn't worked out for me? Any specific reasons ?

Comment: It should work. Can you post some code here? You must be calling performSelectorOnMainThread from some thread and from selector I am assuming you are calling something like [someOtherClassObj updateProgress];    And note that you have to call postNotificationName from main thread so I am wondering how you are calling it

Comment: I tend to use [performSelectorOnMainThread ... waitUntilDone:NO]; instead of "waitUntilDone:YES";  One of the comments also mentions that. I noticed that sometimes setting to "waitUntilDone:YES"; cause the interface to not update. Have you tried setting it to "NO" instead of "YES" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `performSelectorOnMainThread` can be used to run some codes in your main Thread. It not seems to be a method to call a method on another class (Even though you can call the method on another class using this if you have the working instance of the class). If you are using API calls in one of your class, you may have to use seperate threads for performing the API calls as it blocks the main thread (Its not kind to users who use your app). So in the ios you must call the UIKit from main thread only.

The `NSNotification` is used to get a event call. I mean it notifies the observer when occurs a specific event that the observer registerd to be get notified.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: So, I have a class A and B. I am trying to change the label text by calling a method in A FROM B class. It doesn't work. But if I send notification from B to A, the label is changing. How come ?

Comment: In your case, if you have a class A and you pushed another class from A called B. If B contains the same instance of A which pushes B, then you can call the instance on A from B using the instance of A in B.

Answer (score 1):

The class where you make the `performSelectorOnMainThread` call and the `updateProgress` method needed to be in the same class.  If not, (in your case), create a method in the class where `performSelectorOnMainThread` was called and redirect it to the `updateProgress` on the other class.